# Does optimal fitting flat must pass through the mean of the point set?

Tags: linear-algebra, computational-geometry, clustering

I am confused about a statement made in the paper [Linear Time Algorithm for Projective Clustering](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1204.6717.pdf), section 5.1, second paragraph, second line.

Project clustering is a natural generalization of k-means clustering. Given a point set $P$, the goal to find $k$, $j$-dimensional affine spaces(flats) $F_1,\cdots,F_k$, such that the following objective function is minimized

$\sum_{p\in P} \min_{1\leq i \leq k}dist^2(p,F_i)$, where $dist(p,F)$ is the orthogonal distance between point $p$ and flat $F$.

Clearly, as is the case with k-means, the $k$ optimal flats induces a partitioning of the point set $P$, into $k$ subsets $C_1,\cdots,C_k$, such that points in $C_i$ is closer to flat $F_i$ than any other flat $F_j, i\neq j$.

The aforementioned paper (in page 7, third line from last), it is said that "It is easy to see that $F_i$  passes through the mean $o_i$ of $C_i$". I fail to see the simplicity of this. Can someone  please elaborate on that, with a proof sketch?

N.B: mean of a point set $P$ is defined as $\frac{1}{|P|}\sum_{p\in P}p$.

Comment: See the book Foundations of Data Science https://www.cs.cornell.edu/jeh/book.pdf, section 3.9.1.

Comment: @ChandraChekuri ok, I get it. In fact I have managed to prove something similar. I will post this as an answer tomorrow.